# joomla 1.5, Fatal error: Class 'JModelList' not found

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, classnotfound

A joomla site is giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'JModelList' not found in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_joomdoc/libraries/joomdoc/application/component/modellist.php on line 16

I only noticed it this morning when i tried the search, The last time i worked on the site was over a month ago (Installing , removing extentions, fixing errors ....) so i can't really figure out at wich point this error surfaced.

I read somewhere that The class JModelList is not used in Joomla 1.5 (what i'm using) .... i don't know how that could happen because i made sur that the extentions i'm using supported joomla 1.5 and i never made an upgrade.

Just in case, the line 16 of modellist.php is

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');

class JoomDOCModelList extends JModelList { ...
```

Help!

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JModelList is indeed not available in Joomla 1.5. It was introduced with Joomla 1.6.

Apparently the extension isn't compatible with Joomla 1.5 anymore in this case. You have to contact the developer of the extension to get more information or notify him of the bug.

But then, you should upgrade Joomla anyway. You're using an unsupported version.

Comment: i checked again and a found a small indication on the extention description saying it may cause some probleme with 1.5,. The site is not mine to make an upgrade i'm just adding some features to it.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, `JModelList` is not part of Joomla 1.5, so your extension is not compatible to Joomla 1.5.

Joomla does not update anything itselfs. If you have not changed anything, someone else has.

Comment: i checked again and a found a small indication on the extention description saying it may cause some probleme with 1.5.

Comment: "may cause some problems" is a nice description for using completly wrong classes ;)